# Cannot import pygame

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I am not able to import the module Pygame. If any one can tell me a way around this problem I will be happy.Also please check the screenshot for me info. [image: It says import is not recognized]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code! Paste the code!

Comment: The command prompt is not the same as Python. You have to create a file with python code and run it with python, or start a python session by typing `py` in the command prompt.

Comment: Also, refrain of writing things that's not important for the question. Your name, age, and writing *"pls"* is not necessary. Instead, try to only provide information that helps us to help you with your question.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are on a terminal

```
Python
```

type this and now you are able to import pygame.

Comment: You can also start a python session with `Python`